# Looping with .each with delay in Jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each, jquery-isotope

I am not good at jQuery so I am not sure if my assumptions are corrent.

I am using the isotope plugin, with which I want to insert elements one by one (and not everything at once) with a slight delay so it will also look like it (for the human eye)

to insert an item with isotope I use

```
$('#container').isotope( 'insert', $item);
```

so in order to insert one-by-one I am doing

```
$("#items_are_here").find('.item').each(function( index ) {
     setTimeout(function() {
            $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $(this));
         },3000);
    });
```

This however seems that the browser waits for something, and then displays them all at once

If I do

```
  setTimeout(function() {
   $("#items_are_here").find('.item').each(function( index ) {
          $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $(this));

        }); },3000);
```

everything works, but not one-by-one..

Is this the right way to do this? or am I over-complicating it?

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqM6Z/3/). In it, there are 2 buttosn - insert all - which finds all `.item` and inserts them. And insert one-by-one which does the proposed way with delay. As you can see, there is no delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var $items=$("#items_are_here").find('.item');
    var i=-1;
    var delayed=setinterval(function() {
            if (++i<$items.length) $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $items.eq(i));
            else clearInterval(delayed); 
             },3000);
```

not tested.
or

```
    var $container=$('#container');     
    $.fn.extend({
      onebyone :function ($ctnr,i) {
           if (!i) i = 0;
           var $o=$(this);
           setTimeOut(function() {
                 $ctnr.isotope( 'insert', $o.eq(i)); 
                 if (++i<$o.length) $o.onebyone(i); 
               },3000);
           return this; 
      }
    $("#items_are_here").find('.item').onebyone($container);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `.each()` runs pretty instantaneous for each entry, you'll end up with a bunch of timeouts which are more or less the same. So after about 3 seconds, all timeouts expire and the items are added.

To prevent this, you'll to make the timeout dependent on the index of the item. So item 0 will be inserted after 3 seconds, item 1 will be inserted after 6 seconds, etc.

```
$("#items_are_here").find('.item').each(function( index ) {
  var item = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#container').isotope('insert', item);
  },3000 * (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: & there you end up with all those timeOut call running simultaneously :/ (eating up all the ram ? i guess depending on number of items...expect turbulence)

Comment: True :) Your answer using `setInterval()` makes more sense, but that only became clear to me after looking more closely at the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#items_are_here").find('.item').each(function( index ) {
     setTimeout(function() {
            $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $(this));
         },3000);
    });
```

in the above context, `$(this)` is the `window` object, because it's inside `setTimeout`.

Modify your code to and try:

```
$("#items_are_here").find('.item').each(function( index ) {
     var item = $(this);
     setTimeout(function(index) {
            $("#container").isotope( 'insert', $(this))
     },index*3000);
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't give an error, but it doesn't insert it one by one

Comment: Well, i'm not sure what that `isotope` is, so i'm editing my answer with a jquery solution.

Comment: It seems that the browser is waiting for something and then renders it all at once..

Comment: i will attempt to jsfiddle it, hang on

Comment: @NickGinanto try the lastest modified code, that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#items_are_here").find('.item').each(function( index ) {
     var item = $(this);
     setTimeout(function(i) {
            $('#container').isotope( 'insert', i );
         },3000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

little late but my workaround was:
hardcode a class to item like to_animate

the css:

`.item.to_animate {
        opacity:0;
        display:block;
    }
    @keyframes TransitionClass{
        0% { opacity: 0;transform: scale(1.2); }
        100% { opacity: 1;transform: scale(1); }
    }
    .animatefinish.TransitionClass{
        animation-name: umScaleIn;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19,1,.22,1);
    }
    .animatefinish.TransitionClass{
        animation-duration: .8s;
    }`

the snipped for isotope

```
    `$('#container').isotope( 'appended', $(el) ).after(function() {

      $('.item.to_animate').each(function(i) {
      var el = $(this);

              setTimeout(function() {

              el.addClass('TransitionClass animatefinish');

                  el.removeClass('to_animate')

              }, i * 200);

      });

    });`
```