# Applying delay between each iteration of jQuery's .each() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having some problems with the following block of code:

```
        $('.merge').each(function(index) {
            var mergeEl = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.mergeOne(mergeEl, self, index - (length - 1));
            }, 500);
        });
```

I'm trying to apply a .500 second delay between each call of `mergeOne`, but this code only applies a .500 second delay before calling `mergeOne` on all the elements in the array simultaneously.

If someone could explain *why* this code doesn't work and possibly a working solution that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786792/2256325

Comment: You won't be able to use `.each()` (at least properly). You're better off using a recursive function that delays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a general function you can use to iterate through a jQuery object's collection, with a delay between each iteration:

```
function delayedEach($els, timeout, callback, continuous) {
    var iterator;

    iterator = function (index) {
        var cur;

        if (index >= $els.length) {
            if (!continuous) {
                return;
            }
            index = 0;
        }

        cur = $els[index];
        callback.call(cur, index, cur);

        setTimeout(function () {
            iterator(++index);
        }, timeout);
    };

    iterator(0);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Ra9K/ (loop through once)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/42tXp/ (continuous looping)

The context and arguments passed to your callback should be the same as how `.each()` does it.

If you want to make it a jQuery plugin, so it can be called like `$("selector").delayedEach(5000, func...`, then you could use this:

```
$.fn.delayedEach = function (timeout, callback, continuous) {
    var $els, iterator;

    $els = this;
    iterator = function (index) {
        var cur;

        if (index >= $els.length) {
            if (!continuous) {
                return;
            }
            index = 0;
        }

        cur = $els[index];
        callback.call(cur, index, cur);

        setTimeout(function () {
            iterator(++index);
        }, timeout);
    };

    iterator(0);
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VGH25/ (loop through once)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NYdp7/ (continuous looping)

---

**UPDATE**

I added the ability to continuously loop through the elements, as an extra parameter. Passing `true` will continuously loop, while passing `false` or nothing (or something falsey) will only loop over the elements once. The code and fiddles include the changes.

Comment: To fit with convention (such as `setTimeout`), shouldn't it be the callback and THEN the delay?

Comment: @ColinDeClue I don't get what you mean - that's the way it is, isn't it?

Comment: @ian: It is in `setTimeout`, but your function is called `delay, callback`, where `setTimeout` is called `callback, delay`. (As are most of jQuery's functions that DO take a delay)

Comment: @ColinDeClue Ohhhh, you mean like the function's parameters? I thought you meant the workflow of the code. If you meant the parameters, can you give examples of other jQuery methods that do `callback, delay`? In general, I think of the `callback` being the last parameter. Like with `.fadeIn()` and `.slideUp()`, even with `.animate()` (although they don't use a "delay" - they use an overall time for the animation). Am I forgetting something where it's usually the opposite?

Comment: @Ian, yeah, the function parameters, sorry. And I guess for jQuery it's `necessaryThing`, then `delay` (or overall time) THEN callback. So for the `delayEach` I'd lump the "`callback`" (since it's not REALLY a callback, more of an `action`) in with `necessaryThing`. In any case, clearly it's a case of preference. Nice answer.