# How to add delay between two function call with in jQuery each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, jstree

I had a jQuery each loop that creates jstree nodes. After the tree node is created, I want to expand it immediately. Earlier, I was getting issues of all the nodes being created at once instead of one-at-a-time.

```
Test(); //this is being called from another function

function Test() {
    var obj = [{'name': 'Frank', 'age': '23'}, {'name': 'Gina', 'age': '29'}];

    $.each(obj, function(){
        CreateTreeNode(this.name); //function from an external js file
        DoSomething(this.name);
    });
};

function CreateTreeNode(node) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('<li />', {html: node}).appendTo('#tree > ul');
    },1000);
};

function DoSomething(node){
    alert('doing something else for ' + node);
};
```

So I modified the code with the help of various threads in this forum. Like: [Looping with .each with delay in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786537/looping-with-each-with-delay-in-jquery)

Finally I came with this solution that creates the nodes but doesn't expand it. It seems that the expand code runs before nodes are created. To show this function, I have tried to create a simple jsFiddle example. Hope this will help in resolving my problem.
Code Snippet:

```
Test(); //this is being called from another function

function Test() {
    var obj = [{'name': 'Frank', 'age': '23'}, {'name': 'Gina', 'age': '29'}];
    var i = -1;
    var delayed = setInterval(function(){
        if(++i < obj.length){
            CreateTreeNode(obj[i].name); //function from an external js file
            DoSomething(obj[i].name); //Expand the node
        } else {
            clearInterval(delayed)
        }
    }, 3000);
    //ExpandAllNodes(); this didn't work too
};
```

Adding original codebase as per the request from one of the contributor (i know it is some crappy code there). jsTree somehow didn't work without setTimeouts. I am just using this code which is available in external file but I have the liberty to change and I tried changing it as per the recommendation in the comments section and it worked almost except that the last node is not expanded:

```
function zBuildOrderDetailTreeView() {
    var newOrderOptions = '';
    var interval = 500;
    var index = -1;
    var delayed = setInterval(function () {
        if (++index < m_selectedOrderList.length) {
            newOrderOptions = {
                OrderTitle: m_selectedOrderList[index].ShortDescription,
                orderTypeId: m_selectedOrderList[index].SUBDOMAINS,
                CatalogDescription: m_selectedOrderList[index].ShortDescription
            };

            m_cpoeTree.AddOrder(newOrderOptions, m_cpoeTree.ExpandAllNodes);
        } else {
            clearInterval(delayed);
        }
    }, 500);

    // Expand all the nodes by default
    //setTimeout(function () {
    //    m_cpoeTree.ExpandAllNodes();
    //}, m_selectedOrderList.length * 1000);

}

this.AddOrder = function (options, callback) {
    var orderId = _.uniqueId('order_');

    var orderMetadata = { 
        "orderTypeId": options.orderTypeId, 
        "OrderTitle": options.OrderTitle,
        "ConceptId": options.ConceptId,
        "CatalogDescription": options.CatalogDescription,
        "LOINCCode" : options.LOINCCode, 
        "LOINCDescription" : options.LOINCDescription,
        "LOINCTypeCode" : options.LOINCTypeCode, 
        "CPTCode" : options.CPTCode, 
        "CPTDescription" : options.CPTDescription,
        "SNOMEDCode" : options.SNOMEDCode, 
        "SNOMEDDescription" : options.SNOMEDDescription,
        "Diagnoses": options.Diagnoses,
        "FacilityId" : options.FacilityId == undefined ? '' : options.FacilityId,
        "FacilityName" : options.FacilityName == undefined ? '' : options.FacilityName,
        "DueDate" : options.DueDate == undefined ? '' : options.DueDate,
        "PriorityId" : options.PriorityId == undefined ? '' : options.PriorityId,
        "PriorityName" : options.PriorityName == undefined ? '' : options.PriorityName,
        "FastingId" : options.FastingId == undefined ? '' : options.FastingId,
        "FastingName" : options.FastingName == undefined ? '' : options.FastingName,
        "ContrastId" : options.ContrastId == undefined ? '' : options.ContrastId,
        "ContrastName" : options.ContrastName == undefined ? '' : options.ContrastName,
        "SpecialInstructions" : options.SpecialInstructions == undefined ? '' : options.SpecialInstructions
    };

    var orderClass = '';
    switch (options.orderTypeId) {
        case 1:
            if (!orderMetadata.FacilityName || !orderMetadata.DueDate || !orderMetadata.PriorityName || !orderMetadata.FastingName || !orderMetadata.Diagnoses.names) {
                orderClass = ' invalid';
            }
            break;
        default: 
            if (!orderMetadata.FacilityName || !orderMetadata.DueDate || !orderMetadata.PriorityName || !orderMetadata.Diagnoses.names) {
                orderClass = ' invalid';
            }
            break;
    }

    var orderNode = { "title" : orderMetadata.OrderTitle, "state": "open", "li_attr" : { "id" : orderId, "class" : "order" + orderClass, 
    "metadata" : JSON.stringify( orderMetadata) }, "data" : { "class": "mynode" } };

    var matchingObj = zMatchRequisition(orderMetadata);

    if(matchingObj.matchingOrderFound) {
        return '';
    }

    if (!matchingObj.matchingRequisitionFound) {
        that.AddRequisition(matchingObj, options, orderNode, orderId);
    } else {
        that.AddToExistingRequisition(matchingObj, orderNode, orderId, orderMetadata);
    }

    //Creating the context menu for order node
    zCreateOrderContextMenu();
    callback();
    return '#' + orderId;
};

this.AddRequisition = function (options, orderNode, orderId) {
try {
    var reqUniqueId = ++m_uniqueReqId; // Using global vriable that stores the latest requisition id to use on add
    var reqId = 'requsition_' + reqUniqueId;

    var reqMetadata = { 
        "orderTypeId" : options.orderTypeId,
        "Diagnoses": options.Diagnoses,
        "FacilityId" : options.FacilityId == undefined ? '' : options.FacilityId,
        "FacilityName" : options.FacilityName == undefined ? '' : options.FacilityName,
        "DueDate" : options.DueDate == undefined ? '' : options.DueDate,
        "PriorityId" : options.PriorityId == undefined ? '' : options.PriorityId,
        "PriorityName" : options.PriorityName == undefined ? '' : options.PriorityName,
        "FastingId" : options.FastingId == undefined ? '' : options.FastingId,
        "FastingName" : options.FastingName == undefined ? '' : options.FastingName,
        "ContrastId" : options.ContrastId == undefined ? '' : options.ContrastId,
        "ContrastName" : options.ContrastName == undefined ? '' : options.ContrastName,
        "SpecialInstructions" : options.SpecialInstructions == undefined ? '' : options.SpecialInstructions
    };

    var reqClass = 'someclass';
    var reqNode = { "title" : options.title, "state": "open", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId, "class" : "requisition" + reqClass, "metadata" : JSON.stringify(reqMetadata) }, "data" : { } };

    var parentNode = -1;
    var requisitionNode = -1;
    var addClass = '';

    setTimeout(function() {
        that.$container.jstree("create_node", parentNode, reqNode, "last", function () {
            // Set up subnodes                      
            setTimeout(function() {
                var facility = reqMetadata.FacilityName == '' ? 'Facility' : 'Facility: ' + reqMetadata.FacilityName;
                addClass = reqMetadata.FacilityName == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId), { "title" : facility, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId + '_facility', "class" : "facility" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");   
            }, 5);

            setTimeout(function() {
                var dueDate = reqMetadata.DueDate == '' ? 'Due Date' : 'Due Date: ' + reqMetadata.DueDate;
                addClass = reqMetadata.DueDate == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId), { "title" : dueDate, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId + '_duedate', "class" : "duedate" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");  
            }, 5);

            setTimeout(function() {
                var priority = reqMetadata.PriorityName == '' ? 'Priority' : 'Priority: ' + reqMetadata.PriorityName;
                addClass = reqMetadata.PriorityName == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId), { "title" : priority, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId + '_priority', "class" : "priority" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");   
            }, 5);

            if (reqMetadata.orderTypeId == 1 ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var fasting = reqMetadata.FastingName == '' ? 'Fasting' : 'Fasting: ' + reqMetadata.FastingName;
                    addClass = reqMetadata.FastingName == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                    that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId), { "title" : fasting, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId + '_fasting', "class" : "fasting" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");  
                }, 5);   
            }                       

            setTimeout(function() {
                var specialInstructions = reqMetadata.SpecialInstructions == '' ? 'Special Instructions' : 'Special Instructions: ' + reqMetadata.SpecialInstructions;
                that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId), { "title" : specialInstructions, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId + '_specialinstructions', "class" : "specialinstructions" }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last"); 
            }, 5);

            setTimeout(function() {
                that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId), { "title" : "Orders", "state": "open", "li_attr" : { "id" : reqId + '_orders', "class" : "orders" + reqClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last", function() {
                    if (orderNode) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + reqId + '_orders'), orderNode, "last", 
                            function() {
                                // Set up subnodes
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    var diagnoses = reqMetadata.Diagnoses.names == '' ? 'Diagnoses' : 'Diagnoses: ' + reqMetadata.Diagnoses.names;
                                    addClass = reqMetadata.Diagnoses.names == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                                    that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + orderId), { "title" : diagnoses, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : orderId + '_diagnoses', "class" : "diagnoses" + addClass, "title": "Diagnoses: " + options.Diagnoses.names }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");  
                                }, 2);

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    var facility = reqMetadata.FacilityName == '' ? 'Facility' : 'Facility: ' + reqMetadata.FacilityName;
                                    addClass = reqMetadata.FacilityName == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                                    that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + orderId), { "title" : facility, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : orderId + '_facility', "class" : "facility" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");   
                                }, 2);

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    var dueDate = reqMetadata.DueDate == '' ? 'Due Date' : 'Due Date: ' + reqMetadata.DueDate;
                                    addClass = reqMetadata.DueDate == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                                    that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + orderId), { "title" : dueDate, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : orderId + '_duedate', "class" : "duedate" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");  
                                }, 2);

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    var priority = reqMetadata.PriorityName == '' ? 'Priority' : 'Priority: ' + reqMetadata.PriorityName;
                                    addClass = reqMetadata.PriorityName == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                                    that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + orderId), { "title" : priority, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : orderId + '_priority', "class" : "priority" + addClass }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last");   
                                }, 2);

                                // ONLY for LAB
                                if (reqMetadata.orderTypeId == 1 ) {
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        var fasting = reqMetadata.FastingName == '' ? 'Fasting' : 'Fasting: ' + reqMetadata.FastingName;
                                        addClass = reqMetadata.FastingName == '' ? ' invalid' : '';
                                        that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + orderId), { "title": fasting, "state": "closed", "li_attr": { "id": orderId + '_fasting', "class": "fasting" + addClass }, "metadata": { }, "data": { } }, "last");
                                    }, 2);
                                }
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    var specialInstructions = reqMetadata.SpecialInstructions == '' ? 'Special Instructions' : 'Special Instructions: ' + reqMetadata.SpecialInstructions;
                                    that.$container.jstree("create_node", $('#' + orderId), { "title" : specialInstructions, "state": "closed", "li_attr" : { "id" : orderId + '_specialinstructions', "class" : "specialinstructions" }, "metadata" : {}, "data" : { } }, "last"); 
                                }, 2);

                            }); 
                        }, 200);                            
                    }
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        that.$container.jstree("delete_node", '#jstree_waitingfororders');
                    }, 2);
                }); 
            }, 5);


        }); 
    }, 5);

    return '#' + reqId;

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuul13/HPFGQ/5/)

Comment: Why don't you put the delay between "creating the nodes" (all of them) and "expanding them"? And delay may only need to be 0, just the briefest pause to allow the DOM to update.

Comment: will you be able to change the code in `CreateTreeNode`

Comment: the solution should look something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QREZW/1/ ... a callback is passed to `CreateTreeNode` which will be invoked once the node is created

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I have seen that recommendation but I was not sure how should i implement it. CreateTreeNode in the example is very simplified version. But in actual code, CreateTreeNode doesn't have a setTimeout but it is just a wrapper to other methods containing actual timeout functions. The callback solution you recommended, can it be applied on the function that doesn't have timeout? Or, do i need to add timeout in this function too?

Comment: it can be implemented anywhere.... if you can share the `CreateTreeNode` function we can have a look at it... and say where to add the callback invocation

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I added the original code. It is hard t understand but I added if it makes sense. By the way, I tried adding callback to the wrapper method and it actually worked except that the last node does not expand. Side note: i am using jsTree and not sure why do we need so many timeouts.